# Prove $f_{n+1}^2-4f_nf_{n-1}= f_{n-2}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, fibonacci-numbers

I've been trying this proof for a few days now and I keep getting stuck. I'm working with Fibonacci number sequences and have to prove this formula. 
Thank you for helping.

Comment: expand the left and right-hand side of your equation

Comment: Is the formula edited correctly ?

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. I'm still pretty new to this site, thank you for helping @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: You needed curly bracket (not round ones) for your subscripts. Dr SG & Mr YM would have answered your question too if you had stated it accurately ab initio.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{n+1}^2-4f_{n}f_{n-1}=(f_{n}+f_{n-1})^2-4f_{n} f_{n-1}=f_{n}^2+f_{n-1}^2 -2f_{n} f_{n-1} =(f_{n}-f_{n-1})^2=f_{n-2}^2.
\end{eqnarray*}